# more intuitive fuzzy matching helm

Tags: helm

When I use helm fuzzy matching, call `helm-M-x` type `elm` I would like `emacs-lisp-mode` to pop up as a candidate. Instead I get

```
helm-M-x
helm-gid
helm-dash
helm-locate
...
```

I don't find this default fuzzy matching very helpful. How do you achieve more intuitive fuzzy matching?

Looking up how to change this, I found the package `helm-fuzzier` and it looked promising but after installing it didn't work (it seems a bit outdated).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you would have to modify or change the helm-fuzzy rank scoring function. 
Per default, helm fuzzy sort will sort match candidates based on their scores as computed with [helm-score-candidate-for-pattern](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/blob/4c9f2da8d85a087278b41e934bfecff8e0b04fb6/helm.el#L3638).

Now, I don't think any sane algorithm should rank `emacs-lisp-mode` a better candidate match to the search term `elm` than the candidate `helm-M-x`. If you think about it, the pattern `elm` is continuous in `helm`, not so in `emacs-lisp-mode`.

If the pattern is not continuous, then it does make sense to choose the starting letters first. Try searching for `em` instead and you'll see `emacs-lisp-mode` as your first candidate.

The fuzzy algorithm is helpful, provided you let it be helpful on it's on way.

Comment: I don't get `emacs-lisp-mode` as the first candidate or even as a candidate in the visible portion of my minibuffer. I get `emerge-file emacs-version emacs-init-time emacs-index-search...`. I do get it as the fourth when I use `ema`. I respectfully disagree with your assertion that `if the pattern is not contiguous, ... it does not make sense to choose the starting letter...`. For me at least, I find choosing the starting letters first is a lot more useful than contiguous patterns most of the time, particularly because elisp doesn't have namespaces.

Comment: As an example I just made up: trying to find the command `helm-top`. I need to type
`helm-t` find it as per helm's default fuzzy
matching. In contrast using `ivy-regex-fuzzy` which uses a combination of
contiguous and non-contiguous searching, when I type `ht`, I get `helm-top` as
the first candidate. Thank you by the way showing me the function I need to modify to achieve this behavior.

Comment: Do you have any extra configurations set for helm? Check out [Tuhdo's Helm guide](https://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html) and [the spacemacs helm layer](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/master/layers/%2Bcompletion/helm/packages.el) before digging deep into the helm source. Maybe you find some optimizations that better fit your workflow. Good luck!